# Can I install tandem breakers in this panel, and would one 20 ampere circuit be enough for a garage?

Tags: electrical, garage, circuit-breaker, breaker-box

I'm a home owner searching for information before hiring an electrician to come and do work on my home.

What I want:
Have a separate breaker\s to service a single car garage. 3 receptacles each facing each of the walls, two weatherproof receptacles facing outside (control by a switch), 1 outlets for garage door opener (control by a switch; to cutoff when we aren't home), two fluorescents light fixtures and 3 flood motion detection lights.

Job in scope, I'm remodeling my single car garage which its now mainly used for sports/bicycle storage. Reason for remodel is to insulate the walls and I thought since I'm going to have the electrical expose might as well get it updated.

My dilemma: 
Lights and solo-receptacle in the garage were tagged from another line in the house and I do not have any spare space in the panel to add another breaker. I have heard of tandem circuits and do have one installed on a panel (work done by previous home owner). But after doing some search I'm unclear on something.

A) My panel Seimens G1224B1100CU described as 12 space 24 circuits. However, in the legend it doesn't described were the tandem breakers are to be installed. I'm fearing the box is not compatible with this breakers and the one currently installed is not up to code.

B) If the box is compatible to tandem breakers and multiple can be installed. is one 20amp breaker enough for what I want.

Comment: You are asking two questions here. You might want to consider asking them as separate questions.

Answer (score 3):

Your panel is a 12/24, so every space can have a tandem or even quad breaker. That's what 12 space, 24 circuit means. In the panel schedule you may even see a line or dotted line through the middle of each breaker space.

A single 20A breaker can certainly have all that on it, but the question is should it? It all depends on what you will be running simultaneously.

I assume this garage is attached to the house?

Comment: Thank you for the reply Speedy. I did notice that on the panel each of the space has an "a" and "b" side, but I couldn't find any information on the web to validate so. Perhaps I didn't look in the right place.

Comment: btw. Yes the garage is attached to the house. I want to have the items detailed more for convenience. Other than the lights and garage door opener, I do not see me running anything else simultaneously.